# Powershell script Argumentlist not working correctly

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install a rather oldish application. I am wanting to do it in powershell because I have post install functions that need to be done in powershell
The -argumentlist is not starting all the arguments after the /qn ( silent mode install )

The application starts and proceeds to install unattended in silent mode but ignores all the arguments after /qn. So its installing without any of the parameters I have specified. Is there anything I am doing wrong? Could just be my quotes are in the wrong places. My powershell knowledge is very very rusty

```
$workingDirectory = (split-path $myinvocation.mycommand.path -parent)

#Installs my application
Start-Process -Filepath "$workingDirectory\application.exe" -ArgumentList "/args /qn reboot=reallysuppress SILENT=yes INSTALLSTANDALONE=0 CENTRALSERVERHOSTNAME=servername CENTRALSERVERPORT=1234 CSUSER=userName /L*V C:\Windows\Temp\install.log"
```

Comment: Does the path need to contain quotes when it is sent to the program? If so, you can do ```& "$workingDirectory\application.exe" /args /qn reboot=reallysuppress SILENT=yes INSTALLSTANDALONE=0 CENTRALSERVERHOSTNAME=servername CENTRALSERVERPORT=1234 CSUSER=userName /L*V `"C:\Windows\Temp\install.log`"```

Comment: It looks like you are trying commandline switches for installing Msi files. Since you are executing an exe, this may not be valid at all. In a commandbox, try `$workingDirectory\application.exe /?` to see if that way you can retrieve the arguments it can take. Otherwise, try and look up the possible switches on the manufacturers site.

Comment: thanks, but all those arguments are correct as they work in cmd, Just not powershell, ill try with the & statement

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you ran the .EXE directly with those args to verify their correctness?

If that's the case, try this:

```bsh
Start-Process -Filepath "$workingDirectory\application.exe" -ArgumentList "/args", "/qn", "reboot=reallysuppress", "SILENT=yes", "INSTALLSTANDALONE=0", "CENTRALSERVERHOSTNAME=servername", "CENTRALSERVERPORT=1234", "CSUSER=userName", "/L*V", "C:\Windows\Temp\install.log"
```

Or this:

```bsh
Start-Process -Filepath "$workingDirectory\application.exe" -ArgumentList @("/args", "/qn", "reboot=reallysuppress", "SILENT=yes", "INSTALLSTANDALONE=0", "CENTRALSERVERHOSTNAME=servername", "CENTRALSERVERPORT=1234", "CSUSER=userName", "/L*V", "C:\Windows\Temp\install.log")
```

Or this:

```bsh
& "$workingDirectory\application.exe" /args /qn reboot=reallysuppress SILENT=yes INSTALLSTANDALONE=0 CENTRALSERVERHOSTNAME=servername CENTRALSERVERPORT=1234 CSUSER=userName /L*V C:\Windows\Temp\install.log
```

Alternatively, what happens when you remove the `/qn` arg?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your input. Unfortunately none of those worked. When I take out the /qn, it just proceeds to install in attended mode, which I need to click  next > yes > install etc

Comment: @Drekko Try to do the top one but separate `q` and `n` like `Start-Process -Filepath "$workingDirectory\application.exe" -ArgumentList "/args", "/q", "/n", "reboot=reallysuppress", "SILENT=yes", "INSTALLSTANDALONE=0", "CENTRALSERVERHOSTNAME=servername", "CENTRALSERVERPORT=1234", "CSUSER=userName", "/L*V", "C:\Windows\Temp\install.log"`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue.

Changed this:

```
& "$workingDirectory\application.exe" /args /qn reboot=reallysuppress SILENT=yes INSTALLSTANDALONE=0 CENTRALSERVERHOSTNAME=servername CENTRALSERVERPORT=1234 CSUSER=userName /L*V C:\Windows\Temp\install.log
```

To this:

```
& "$workingDirectory\application.exe" /qn reboot=reallysuppress SILENT=yes INSTALLSTANDALONE=0 CENTRALSERVERHOSTNAME=servername CENTRALSERVERPORT=1234 CSUSER=userName /L*V C:\Windows\Temp\install.log
```

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx